# Access spinner declared in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a spinner that i populate with an array list from a resource. I have it populated and the code is compiling correctly. My problem now is that I can't seem to figure out how to access the spinner from my main class. For instance, I have my class  "CreateExerciseActivity" where I have my method "createExercise"

```
public class CreateExerciseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_create_exercise_activiy);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public void createExercise(View view){

        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        DataBaseWrapper dbHandler = new DataBaseWrapper(this);

        Exercise exercise = new Exercise(name.getText().toString(), category);
        dbHandler.addExercise(exercise); 
        name.setText("");
    }
}
```

And below is the code for my fragment where I initialize and populate the spinner

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    private Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_exercise_activiy,
                        container, false);
        loadSpinnerCategories(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadSpinnerCategories(View view){
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.categories,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I want to know how I can access my spinner from the first class "CreateExerciseActivity" now that it has been populated from the fragment. I want to be able to take the option someone has selected and enter it into the database along with exercise name in the method "createExercise".

Comment: You are using layout(xml) for both activity and fragment same `fragment_create_exercise_activiy.xml` then populate spinner in activity or add click function inside fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways of doing this.

Usually, you want to respond to some type of event in the fragment. For example, a button is pressed. From the fragment you can call the activity like this:

```
CreateExerciseActivity activity = (CreateExerciseActivity) getActivity();
activity.createExercise(....);
```

A better way would be for the activity to implement an interface IOptionSelectedListener for example. The interface could have a method called OnOptionSelected(value). Then you could do:

```
IOptionSelectedListener listener = (IOptionSelectedListener) getActivity();
listener.OnOptionSelected(....);
```

You could also pass the activity reference to the newInstance() method of the fragment, instead of calling getActivity().

The activity could also have a reference to the fragment and call a method on the fragment to get the actual value of the spinner.